# I want to design a punch timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to create a virtual punch machine where employee can punch in and punch out. It has been a while since i have touched `T-SQL` and some concept have lost their way in my memory.

I created a table with the punch informations

```
CREATE TABLE Punchs
(
    id                  INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    idEmployee          INT NOT NULL,
    punchIn             DATETIME NOT NULL,
    punchOut            DATETIME,

    FOREIGN KEY (idEmployee) REFERENCES Employees(id)
)
```

I keepp some sinple information as a id for the `id` of the punch, `idEmployee` for the employee account number, `punchIn` as for the time the employee punched in for work and `punchOut` for when the employee quit.

I would like to make a procedure that will know if it needs to punch in or to punch out.

I have a specification though

- If the day is a new day, start a new punch

What i have so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Punch
(
    @idEmployee INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF((SELECT statut FROM Employee WHERE idEmployee = @idEmployee) = 1)
    BEGIN TRY
        --If there is an active punch
        IF((SELECT TOP 1 punchOut FROM Punchs WHERE idEmployee = @idEmployee) = NULL)
        BEGIN
            --If the punch is the same date than the punchIn
            IF("Day is today") -- <- i have trouble here
                UPDATE Punchs SET punchOut = GETDATE() WHERE idEmployee = @idEmplyee
            --If the punch is in a different day
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Punchs(idEmployee, punchIn) VALUES (@idEmployee, GETDATE())
                EXEC SendPunchError(@idEmployee)
            END
        END
        --If there are no active punch
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Punchs(idEmployee, punchIn) VALUES (@idEmployee, GETDATE())
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: your ID is an identity column. How would you expect the app to pass in the ID to puch out ? You should pass in @idEmployee instead to the stored procedure

Comment: @squirrel my bad, you are right. I wrote it too fast i guess :P I edited it

Comment: You'll need to recognize and account for unusual conditions, such as lost punches, missing punches, duplicate punches, etc. You'll also need to have a way for supervisors to edit punches and add or remove punches. AND if a supervisor edits a punch the fact that the supervisor edited it must be immediately clear, including WHO edited it, what the ORIGINAL data was, what the NEW data is, and the date/time when the record was modified. Ditto for supervisor adds and deletes. Been there. Done that. :-)

Comment: @bobjarvis So i'll need to improve my punch table in order to make it more precise. Did'nt thought of that. Thanks for the advise. +1

Comment: Any time you're dealing with payroll-related data there are (at least) two concerns: 1) auditors get REAL PICKY about money issues, so this is an area where you implement every CYA technique known to programmer-kind, e.g. don't perform calculations; instead, require that the user input the values. If something goes wrong and there's fingers being pointed you want to be sure that the fingers are pointing at someone else. 2) People who are punching in and out are generally not highly paid. Executives may not notice minor pay issues - but the hourly guy whose check is short $11.73 WILL spot it!

Comment: @BobJarvis Noted! But how to implements user input if i would, for example, implements a single button touch for the punch in and out? any idea? The only thing i can think of is the `SQL` `GETDATE()` function. Sorry if my question can seems confused, english is not my native language.

Comment: Perhaps I've confused things here. When I said "require that the user input the values" I was referring to punch overrides and that sort of thing.

Comment: @BobJarvis Ok i see. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses MERGE. The checking principal is the same.

```
; 
WITH
active AS
(
    SELECT  id, e.idEmployee, punchIn
    FROM    Employee e
            LEFT JOIN Punchs p  ON  e.idEmployee    = p.idEmployee
                                AND p.punchOut      is null
    WHERE   e.idEmployee    = @idEmployee
)
MERGE   Punchs AS t
        USING   
        (
            select  id, idEmployee
            from    active

            UNION ALL

            -- this is to handle the condition "If the day is a new day, start a new punch"
            SELECT  id = NULL, idEmployee
            FROM    active
            WHERE   convert(date, punchIn)  <> convert(date, getdate())
        ) AS s
        ON  s.id        = t.id
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
        THEN

        INSERT (idEmployee, punchIn) 
        VALUES (@idEmployee, getdate())

WHEN    MATCHED
        THEN

        UPDATE SET 
        punchOut        = getdate();
```

Comment: what is the benefit of this method over the other?

Comment: using `MERGE` you only write one single query. The other is multiple query statement. For more complex `INSERT`, `UPDATE` requirement, like involve multiple table etc, `MERGE` will not be able to handle

Answer (score 1):

i have edited your procedure, see the in-line comments on the changes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Punch
(
    @idEmployee INT
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @id INT, @punchIn DATETIME;

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- you don't required this, if you have Foreign Key to the Employee table
--IF((SELECT statut FROM Employee WHERE id = @id) = 1)

BEGIN TRY
    --If there is an active punch
    --active punch means no punch out. Get that ID
    SELECT @id = id, @puchIn = punchIn
    FROM   Punchs
    WHERE  idEmployee = @idEmployee
    AND    punchOut IS NULL

    -- IF Active Punch
    IF   @id is not null   
    BEGIN
        --If the punch is the same date than the punchIn
        -- Convert to DATE and compare
        IF(CONVERT(DATE, @punchIn) = CONVERT(DATE, getdate()) -- <- i have trouble here
            UPDATE Punchs SET punchOut = GETDATE() WHERE id = @id
        --If the punch is in a different day
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Punchs(idEmployee, punchIn) VALUES (@id, GETDATE())
            EXEC SendPunchError(@id)
        END
    END
    --If there are no active punch
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Punchs(idEmployee, punchIn) VALUES (@id, GETDATE())
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
END
```